# What is the point of the Destination Wheel?

Tags: chibi-robo-zip-lash

So the Destination Wheel moves me 1,2, or 3 levels once I finish a world. What's the point of this? Will I ever want to skip levels? Do I have to finish each level in a world to complete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wheel is straightforward, what you land on is how many spaces forward you move. There is no ability to freely select stages until you clear all stages and the boss in a world.

IF you land on a cleared level you *will* be forced to play it again, with no real benefit other than you can find the alien child (good for a treasure chest) on the second playthrough, or any collectables you missed. As a tiny act of mercy, a large SKIP button lets you skip any intro/outro/midlevel cutscenes when replaying.

Counterintuitively, there is pretty much never a reason to skip a level (unless you already skipped). Going one by one is the best course of action as you have to play all the levels anyway.

You can buy pieces to make the wheel easier, but this is per-spin and not generally worth it unless for example you only have one spin and all choices but one would mean missing the last uncleared level.